# Why does a iframe that executes a heavy script freeze the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

iframe is inserted into the parent page:

```
<iframe width = "500" height = "500" src = "/ Home / Myscript"> </ iframe>
```

The following script is executed in the iframe:

```
 var i = 0;
    var s = '';
    while (i <100000000) {
       s+ = 'q';
       i ++;
    }
```

The iframe when the script is running heavily fills up RAM and the parent page freezes. A web worker in the iframe helped me, but I thought the iframe should work asynchronously and not affect the parent page.

1) Why does the iframe slow down the parent page (the page does not respond to anything)?

2) Is the iframe asynchronous?

Comment: The frame code is not asynchronous, as you have determined by experiment :)

Comment: Pointy already gave you the correct answer, but I have to ask, what is the purpose of that code? To fill a variable with 100 million "q"s?

Comment: What is the purpose? That is for the author of that script to tell you. My guess is they do not want you to frame the page.

Comment: It *might* be possible for an `<iframe>` with other-domain content to have its own concurrent execution environment, but I don't know that for sure. When it's the same domain, it kind-of has to be synchronous because the code domains can interact.

Comment: I tried to fill the line to the maximum with this script, but found that the concatenation is very hard on the RAM. Instead of the expected 20 MB for 10,000,000 characters, I got 1 GB.